# Set Default Current date in parameter fields Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem with Crytal Report (CR) 2013, my customer want to default current date in parameter fields in Crytal Report when they open it. I try to do it with many ways but it not work. i'm looking forward to ur help. Tks all.
[Current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aygSp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to set a current date to a report parameter is by adding your report as a subreport and passing a formula returning current date as a source for the parameter. You may add also a parameter for date in the main report and inside the formula check if the provided value is for example 1/1/1900 then use current date. This will work if you do not have subreports in your report ( Crystal does not support nested subreports) and the user should be aware that date 1/1/1900 should be selected for current date.

Generally speaking default values should be handled by the software , which is running the report. Ask your customer to try application like this one: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx.

I am posting the link because this software is free. My guess is that there are other applications , which are able to set default values for report parameters. You can do your research. Here is a sample video setting a default value for date: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_ParameterTemplates.aspx

The video is for different report type, but Crystal reports will be handled in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I am a colleage of Hai Pham. I give you more information about this issue.
1. datasource: stored procedure
2. set current date is default value in import parameters popup
[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afm31.png)

3. users can select another value

Thanks,
Dai Nguyen Quang.